# Cannot Read Sheet Range From Null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that allows me to import spreadsheet data from my gmail to Google Sheets. Previously, the spreadsheet data had only had 6 columns to import. Now, some new changes are made and a 7th column was added. After this change was implemented, my function no longer works and Google Sheets throws this error. May I please have some assistance?

So, as I'm looking at this, the intended functionality looks right to me. Skip the first 3 rows (`netdata`) and take everything below. Could it be the `+ 1, 1` ?

**The Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
```

**My import function:**

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var sheetName = "SHEET_NAME"; // Name of sheet tab. 
  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:EMAIL HERE label:LABEL HERE"); // "from:recipient email here label:name of your filter/label here"


  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0]; // [0] will by default look for only 1 attachment. If there are more than two attachment increase value. ex: [1] , [2] 

  var data = [];
  if (attachment.getContentType() == MimeType.CSV) { // This will look for a CSV file type first
    data = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

  } else if (attachment.getContentType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || attachment.getContentType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) { // If attachment is an xls, this line will look at the content to determine and convert accordingly.

    var tempFile = Drive.Files.insert({title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, attachment).id;

    data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
    Drive.Files.trash(tempFile);
  }
  if (data.length > 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var netdata = data.slice(3); // This will skip the number of rows starting from the top.
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, netdata.length, netdata[0].length).setValues(netdata );
  }
}
```

**I'm think the issue is here:**

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, netdata.length, netdata[0].length).setValues(netdata );
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but peraps after you open the tempFile it becomes the active spreadsheet. Then you put it in trash. Then you're calling an activeSpreadsheet and getting none because it's removed. Try to move the line `var sheet=activeSpreadsheet...` upward. Before you open and remove another spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't think that would be the issue as that is part of the conversion that is needed to happen. As stated, this was already working when there was only 6 columns in the spreadsheet attachment. Now that there's 7 columns, I don't understand what about having the extra column affected this code.

Comment: I just tried your script and it work fine for any number of columns in Excel file. I tried xls and xlsx formats. There can be something wrong with your Excel files. But most likely it's just wrong sheet name, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the issue is with the `sheet` variable being null. That happens when there is no sheet by the name `SHEET_NAME` in the spreadsheet.

To fix the error, replace `SHEET_NAME` with the name of the sheet you want the function to work with. Check for things like leading and trailing whitespace in the sheet's name.